# When was a block blob created in azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

The blob reference contains a `Properties` property that has a `LastModified` of `DateTimeOffset?`. However, I can't find when was the creation date(time) of the blob. Is there a standard API I can use or I need to store that in the meta?

```
    public async Task<IBlobMeta> GetBlobMetaAsync(string blobId)
        {
            if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(blobId))
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(blobId));

            var blob = await EnsureGetBlobById(blobId);
            await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();

            string clientBlobName;
            blob.Metadata.TryGetValue(BlobNameMetaKey, out clientBlobName);

            var length = blob.Properties.Length;
            var md5 = blob.Properties.ContentMD5;
            var lastModified = blob.Properties.LastModified.Value.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;
            var dateCreated= blob.Properties.???????;
            return new AzureBlobMeta(blobId, clientBlobName, length, md5, dateCreated);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Created` date property has been added in Storage Client Library, starting with [version 9.2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/releases/tag/v9.2.0):

> Blobs: Added support for blob creation time property.

(Available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/9.2.0) since May 23 '18)

Here's how it's declared in [BlobProperties.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/v9.2.0/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobProperties.cs#L132):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the the creation time for the blob, expressed as a UTC value.
/// </summary>
/// <value>A <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/> containing the blob's creation time, in UTC format.</value>
public DateTimeOffset? Created { get; internal set; }
```

The type is nullable DateTimeOffset, same as `LastModified` property.

---

The source of the value comes from `x-ms-creation-time` header in the REST API, which was added in [version 2017-11-09](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob#response-headers):

> `x-ms-creation-time` Version 2017-11-09 and newer. The date/time at which the blob was created. The date format follows RFC 1123.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a standard API I can use or I need to store that in the meta?

As of today, you would need to store this information in form of blob metadata. There's no API which would tell you when a blob was created. `Last Modified` property of the blob tells you when a blob was last modified. This could be because a blob's content was changed or either it's properties or metadata was changed.

Comment: please what is the reason behind it? Why it is not possible to surface this information thru API?

Answer (score 0):

It is available in class `CloudBlob` then `Properties.Created` over package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/)