# Azure Boot Diagnostics Screenshot not working after manually changing Storage Account in Diagnostics Settings

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, diagnostics

I had a bunch of Resource Manager VMs configured to use Diagnostic Settings with all VMs using the same storage account.

I accidentally deleted the storage account these VMs were using for diagnostics.  Then, I created a new Storage account with the same name, and manually changed the storage account for each VM to use this new storage account under "Diagnostic Settings".  I also made sure the "Boot Diagnostics" checkbox was checked under "Diagnostic Settings", and that "Status" was set to "On".

I created the new storage account as "Standard" (Performance) and "Locally-redundant storage" (LRS) in the same region.

Previously, when I rebooted a machine, I could see it's screenshot under "Boot diagnostics".   With my new configuration, the "Boot diagnostics" screen is always blank even after multiple reboots.

Is there some additional step I need to do to get "Boot Diagnostics" to again show me these screenshots?  Did I do something wrong in setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I test in my lab. If I delete diagnostics storage account, when I recreate it, I could get Boot Diagnostics. Please check as the following ways.

1.Reset your browser or try to use another browsers.

2.Check containers in your storage account. If there is no container in the storage account, try to create a new container name like `bootdiagnostics-shui-7d7420ff-0ab1-43d8-842e-d628ef1f857e`. Then, try to set `Diagnostic Settings` again.

I suggest you select `Basic metrics` when you configure `Diagnostic Settings`.

Comment: Could you check extension `LinuxDiagnostic` status? If it is fail, you could unistall it and try again.

Comment: Thanks much for your response, but I still can't get the Boot Diagnostics screenshot to work.  I've tried using different browsers.  Running Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, I saw a bunch of blob containers already created for my machines.  I was also able to create the blob container you suggested.  I also tried turning on Basic Metrics.  I've noticed that the other machines I have that correctly show the "Boot Diagnostics" screens only have "Boot Diagnostics" checked under "Diagnostic Settings", but don't actually have a storage account configured.  Any other ideas?

Comment: These are all Windows 7 VMs, so I don't think the LinuxDiagnostic Extension is relevant.

Comment: Windows also has a Diagnostic extension, if possible, you could check.

Comment: Mysteriously, the Boot Diagnostics screenshot starting working on 24 out of 25 of my Windows 7 VMs this morning.  Every night these machines are set to auto-shutoff, and when I started them today, they all worked.  To answer your last question, these machines all have IaaSDiagnostics successfully configured.  I'm wondering if it was just a transient Azure problem...

Comment: The screen picture stores on storage account. It stores as  a blob. You could check the blob created time.

Comment: The blobs show that they were modified on Friday.  I can't find a way to determine the creation time using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer or the Portal.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518637/how-to-retrieve-azure-blob-storage-file-attributes-such-as-create-data-and-audit# indicates that there is no way to get these creation dates.  If you know of a way to get these creation dates, please let me know.

Comment: @Based on my knowledge, Azure does not support `creation data` for a blob for now.