# Is Azure blob create time Monotonically increasing?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, distributed-system

If I create blob1 first and wait until it gets created,

then I create blob2 in the same container, is it possible that blob2 creation time is lesser than blob1's creation time?

For defination of blob time this can be reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#response-headers

EDIT:
More explaination on why this can happen:

Creation of blob1 & blob2 can be handled by different servers (lets say server1 and server2).

If server2 clock is behind by server1 then even though request for blob2 was later, its creation time can be earlier to blob1.

In distributed systems, such clock drift[1] exists. If monotonicity property exists then its generally explicitly mentioned like in azure table storage[2], cosmosdb[3], etc.
For azure blob I don't find any place they have mentioned that monotonicity exists or not, hence was asking if someone has figured this out.

[1] "On a network" section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew

[2]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#timestamp-property

[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#guarantees-associated-with-consistency-levels

Comment: If blob1 is created before blob2, then the creation time for blob1 will always be lesser than that of blob2.

Comment: What is the purpose of your question ? I mean what do you have in mind ? Why are you asking this question ? Could you explain your use case /thoughts

Comment: Create time is monotonically increasing, but I am afraid I misunderstood your mean, Is this what you want to know?

Comment: There is no single clock in distributed system, if blob1 creation request goes to server1 and blob2 creation request goes to server2, and then if server2 clock is behind server1 by good amount(lets say 10 mins), then blob2 will have earlier time even though someone created blob2 after blob1

Comment: Some suggestions including metadata / table storage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518637/how-to-retrieve-azure-blob-storage-file-attributes-such-as-create-data-and-audit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the create time is monotonically increasing. If you create blob2 after created blob1,the create time of blob2 can not be earier than blob1.

Comment: Any reference? Please see my question EDIT which includes more explanation on why this can happen.